# how to write an "@" with pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x

So basically This is my code:

```
randnum = random.randint(1, 999999)
randomname = "justalollipop" + str(randnum)
randomemail = randomname + "@gmail.com"
```

And after that I want to write it into a login field with pyAutoGUI with `pyautogui.typewrite(randomemail)`

The problem now is, that everytime it tries to write this, it just writes without the `@`

Edit: I know that `@` is an operator.

Edit//2:
So I basically looked into pyAutoGUI and found out that the code has to be

```
pyautogui.typewrite(randomname)
pyautogui.keyDown('altright')
pyautogui.keyDown('q')
pyautogui.keyUp('altright')
pyautogui.keyUp('q')
pyautogui.typewrite("gmail.com")
```

Instead of just

```
pyautogui.typewrite(randomemail)
```

Thank you for the answers

Answer (score 2):

Best answer I've found after many tries:

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy("@")
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
```

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation states](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html?highlight=typewrite)

> You can only press single-character keys with typewrite(), so you
>   can’t press the Shift or F1 keys, for example.

Why don't you try:

```
pyautogui.typewrite(randomemail)
pyautogui.press('@')  
pyautogui.typewrite("gmail.com")
```

P.S. Maybe is just an encoding problem and it's possible to pass the `@` encoded. But I really don't know the inner internals of pyautogui.

I used to use [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) but it only supports windows as the name states.

Comment: In Windows, to get @, you would do:

    pyautogui.hotkey('altright','2')

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pyautogui.hotkey("altright","q")
```